# in Qt setFocus() for QGraphicsItemGroup

Tags: qt

How to be given setFocus() properties into  QGraphicsItemGroup item?
I have 3 GraphicsRectItem in QGraphicsItemGroup with bondingrect()
and I want to give setfocus() preporty this QGraphicsItemGroup to can be controled with keyPressEvent

Comment: Having an example of the code you are having problems to helps in troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

Although your question does not provide enough details, but it seems that you have some graphics items inside a group, and you want to control the items through the keyboard, right?
If so, let's assume that you have some `QGraphicsItem` items in a `QGraphicItemGroup` and you want to change the active item by using the `Tab` key and then do some actions on the active item by using other keys (e.g., rotate it or so on).
My solution is as follows:

1. define a `QGraphicsItem *activeItem` pointer which will point to the active item in the group.
2. overriding the group's `keyPressedEvent` function as follows:

```
void MainWindow::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
    //Which key is pressed? ---> <QKeyEvent> must be included
    if (event->key() == Qt::Key_Tab) {

        /* set activeItem as you desire.
         * For example, find the index of the
         * item that currently activeItem is pointing
         * to and then go to the next item.
        */

        //then return
    }

    if (event->key() == Qt::Key::YourDesiredKey) {

        //do your actions and then return
    }

}
```

Comment: Shapes *left = new Shapes();
Shapes *rigth = new Shapes();
Shapes *up = new Shapes();
Shapes *down = new Shapes();


 up->setRect(X0+20,Y0,20,20);
 left->setRect(X0,Y0,20,20);
 down->setRect(X0,Y0+20,20,20);
 rigth->setRect(X0+20,Y0+20,20,20);

 QGraphicsItemGroup *ig = new QGraphicsItemGroup();

 ig->addToGroup(left);
 ig->addToGroup(up);
 ig->addToGroup(rigth);
 ig->addToGroup(down);

 ig->childrenBoundingRect();
 ig->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsFocusable);
 ig->setFlag(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable, true);

 scene->addItem(ig);
 ig->setFocus();

Comment: Sorry  I wrote its codes but I think there is a problem in appereance

Comment: Please do not put your code here in the comments. Press Edit below your question and add your code to your question by putting it between three ` at the beginning and other three ` at the end of your code.